# Form validation with Jquery or other without id name or class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I have no idea how to solve the Problem maybe some one can help.

I have a dynamic form that duplicate pices of the form depending on the user input.

So i cant use ids because the will be not uniq (Jquery Val. plugin).

I cant use classes because the are used for layout things ...

I cant use names because the are used to post in an array ...

So where to hook up the validation ?

Some one have tips for me ?

Thank you !!!

Comment: Why can't you use classes? An element can have multiple classes, so you can have some classes for layout and other classes for validation.

Comment: Thx for the Comment i have try it before but when i add a secound class the layout will break and rewrite the whole layout of the application to get one form validated :-( ...

Comment: That shouldn't happen. CSS doesn't care about extra classes.

Comment: Its right it shouldnt't happen but it happens ... sadly i have to work with the given old horrible layout (not my coding) or i have to write it complet new ... i have only to add few forms i think its cost less time to find a workaround ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have same validation type for each input group, and I am sure that you generate a new name for the new input right?

When you duplicate the input with `name="field"` .. make the duplicated `name="field-2"`

In jQuery use start with selector to validate these fields

```
$( "input[name^='field']" ) // This will match field and field-2
```

**More Advanced Method:**

If you need to access these dynamic fields. You will need to generate your own `data-Anything`

When you have an input such as

```
<input type="text" name="field" data-order="0" data-type="mytype" data-duplicated="FALSE">
```

The duplicated can be like this

```
 <input type="text" name="field2" data-order="1" data-type="mytype" data-duplicated="TRUE">
```

Then access the second one like this in jQuery

```
$("input").each(function(index){
    if($(this).data("type") == "mytype" && $(this).data("order") == 0){
        // validate
    }
});
```

To access all duplicated using order or duplicated field. you can use what you want.

```
$("input").each(function(index){
    if($(this).data("type") == "mytype" && $(this).data("order") > 0){
        // validate
    }
});
```

So, basically you can define your data-attributes as the way you want dynamically, and access them by looping through the current inputs in the HTML page. When you find the input apply the validation function immediately.

Comment: THANKS i am a dummy .... i use the same to disable input fields so why not for valitation ... *tilt*